# Big Space between TableRows

Tags: android, layout, space, tablerow

I have the problem, that between my TableRows I have big spaces. How can I remove them? I set margin and padding with `0dp` but there is no change.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:padding="0dp"

>

<TableLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_ohne"



     >
<TableRow 
    android:layout_weight="1"
   >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Herzlichen Glückwunsch! Dein Highscore beträgt: " />
</TableRow>
<TableRow 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPunkte"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Dein Name"
        android:inputType="text|textCapSentences" >

 <requestFocus /> </EditText>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Deine E - Mail Adresse"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >

    </EditText>
</TableRow>

<TableRow 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etWohnort"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Dein Wohnort"
        android:inputType="text|textCapSentences" />
</TableRow>




<TableRow 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbNewsletter"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Für Wüstenfest Newsletter eintragen"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btHighscore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/highscoresenden"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvVerlosung"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Um an der Verlosung teilzunehmen, musst du Name, E-Mail Adresse und Wohnort richtig ausfüllen:" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove this from your xml code wherever you see in Table Row:

```
android:paddingTop="10dp"
```

Check box with

```
android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
```

And you are done.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I still have this big space like you see in the screenshot I added!

Comment: Then stop giving unnecessary weight.

Comment: Unless I suggest you to use Linear Layout instead of TableLayout. It will be easy to use.